# React-Native, Dynamic ReactNavigation title

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a screen that it's title should set from `AsyncStorage` and many screens are navigating to this screen (so I don't want pass the title everywhere I'm navigating).

As `navigationOptions` is `static` I'm not able to use `this.state` and also can't set it's title by reading from `AsyncStorage` (because `AsyncStorage` is **Async** :)

How can I change the title inside the screen itself in such a situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`setParams`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#setparams-make-changes-to-route-params) navigation action to set the title after async function ends.

**Example**

```
class SomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params } = navigation.state;

    return {
      title: params ? params.screenTitle: 'Default Screen Title',
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('someValueToGet').then((value) => {
      this.props.navigation.setParams({screenTitle: value})
    });
  }

  // OR You can wait for the someValueToGet

  async componentDidMount() {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('someValueToGet');
    this.props.navigation.setParams({screenTitle: value})
  }

  /* render function, etc */
}
```